# AngularJS Bootstrap: Limit typeahead results

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a simple text field that uses typeahead with results from an array. I would like to limit user input to ONLY be able to type/select results in the array.

If my array looked like this:

```
['alison','bentley','christopher'];
```

The user could type `'ali'`, or `'topher'`, but in the end, the typeahead should select whatever is currently highlighted (if the input blurs), or the user selects.

However, the user should not be able to type `'z'`, because it matches nothing in the array. It shouldn't let them type that at all.

Does this already exist, or do I need to create a custom directive? I searched other similar questions, but they weren't quite the same.

I tried using `typeahead-editable`, because I thought that was what I needed, but it prevented the typeahead from working entirely. On the bootstrap website, it describes it as  `"Should it restrict model values to the ones selected from the popup only?"` Am I doing something incorrectly?

[Here is a plunker:](http://plnkr.co/edit/lwhA9sWNSGrMHhkndy7b?p=preview)

If you remove `typeahead-editable`, the basic typeahead should work.

Answer (score 10):

By default Typeahead doesn't filter the array, you need to declare it using `filter:$viewValue`, e.g.

```
<input 
  ng-model="name"
  typeahead="address for address in locations | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:5" />
```

Here is a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/79nIZGercNSYPaso04yT?p=preview)